# How do I print text in Common Lisp so that I could format it with escape sequences (akin to display in Racket)?

Tags: formatting, common-lisp, stdout

Ho do I print a formatted output in Common Lisp?
In [Racket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_(programming_language)) I do it with `display`, like so:

```
(display "\33[3min italics\33[m\n")
```

I've tried with `(format t "~ain italics~a" "\33[3m" "\33[m")` but it does not work. Neither does this: `(format t "~cin italics~c" #\33[3m #\33[m)`.

Comment: what should it do? Where would the output appear? That' would be Terminal output?

Comment: @RainerJoswig It should print the text the shell. It is meant to be a part of an interactive CLI app.

Comment: what about `(format t "~ain italics~a" "\\33[3m" "\\33[m")` ? (escaping slashes)

Comment: Two helper libraries: [cl-ansi-term](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-ansi-term/) (supports colors, italics, simple lines, borders and tables) and [cl-ansi-term](https://github.com/pnathan/cl-ansi-text), for ANSI colors.

Comment: @Ehvince Sadly, `(format t "~ain italics~a" "\\33[3m" "\\33[m")` does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue here is how to get the proper sequence of characters. \33 is octal for ascii char 27 or #\Esc in Common Lisp.

```lisp
(format t "~C[3min italics~C[m~%" #\Esc #\Esc)
```

would do what you want.

But you could do better than that. There is a library called [cl-interpol](http://edicl.github.io/cl-interpol/) which demonstrates flexibility of Common Lisp by modifying the reader so you could use the already familiar syntax.
For example:

```
* (ql:quickload 'cl-interpol)
To load "cl-interpol":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-interpol
; Loading "cl-interpol"
...
(CL-INTERPOL)

* (named-readtables:in-readtable :interpol-syntax)
#<NAMED-READTABLE :INTERPOL-SYNTAX {1002E6D6B3}>

* (format t #?"\33[3min italics\33[m\n")
in italics
NIL
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I've tried to incorporate your solution into my custom function `i`, sadly all my attempts fail:`(defun i (x) (let p (concatenate 'string "\33[3m" x "\33[m") (format t #?"~A" p)));Malformed LET bindings: P.`  `(defun i (x) (let (p (concatenate 'string "\33[3m" x "\33[m") (format t #?"~A" p)));The LET binding spec (CONCATENATE 'STRING "33[3m" X "33[m") is malformed.`  `(defun i (x) (let ((p (concatenate 'string "\33[3m" x "\33[m")) (format t #?"~A" p))));The LET binding spec (FORMAT T "~A" P) is malformed.` The comments show that I do not have proper `let`. Would you help me?

Comment: (LET P ...) makes so sense. Check the LET syntax.

Comment: (LET (FORMAT ...)) also makes no sense.

Comment: See the syntax of LET: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm#let

Comment: If you are using cl-interpol, then you neither have to manually concatenate strings nor use format. see the "interpolation" section on the cl-interpol doc page. when you understand how to use $(), you could write your function as `(defun i (x) (princ #?"\33[3m$(x)\33[m\n"))`. You could use format instead of princ, but don't use format directives with cl-interpol. It will only confuse you further.